# R) Why te() has a "cr" for default basis option in mgcv package?

Tags: r, mgcv

In the mgcv package, s() term has a bs option with "tp" as a default value.

As I understand, "tp" is a optimal smoother for any dimension or rank, so it is used for default.

But in case of te() term, "cr" is the default, not a "tp"

Is there a reason for using cubic regression spline for the te() term?

And is it ok to use "tp" for a bs option in te() term?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Q1

For speed / efficiency reasons. It is incredibly simple to set up and form the tensor product basis from marginal cubic regression spline bases. If you are modelling 2+ dimensional effects that typically implies you have a lot of data and setting up the (otherwise mgcv-) default thin plate regression spline bases for the margins would likely incur unreasonable set-up time. There's little reason to incur this set-up cost.

#### Q2

Yes, it is entirely fine to use the TPRS basis as a marginal smooth in a tensor product smooth.